# jasper report: generation of simple jrxml to display db table

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have very large number of db tables in pracle database. I would like to somehow generate simple jasper report (version 6.0.3) for each of them.

One line with the name of table as header and under it common table displaying all columns of table. Option to exclude some columns from predefined list is welcome.

Any advise? Has someone any experience with this issue?

Thank in advance

My idea is use some ETL tool for extract specification of tables directly from database and map it somehow into xml files

Answer (score 2):

There is a cloud based tool that generates the JRXML transparently based on the data structure, you can check it out at http://flashreport.io.

It supports simple XML and JSON as input, but does not allow excluding specific columns. You would have to do that in your ETL tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***iReports***, which is a designing tool for generating jrxml files (which are jasper-reports xml files): [iReports tutorial](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-tutorials-help). You have just to create a data-source (in this case you can create a connection to your DB), and construct your report design by dragging and dropping the tables/columns into it (mapped from the underlying data-source). 
I've personally been working this iReports, but nowadays the jaspersoft community is putting it's efforts into another tool: [Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/designing-report-jaspersoft-studio), which seems to be the future replacement for **iReports**

Comment: Thank you for answer. I also work with **IReports** tool, but I would like to generate jrxml automatically. I have more than hundred db tables and their number can raise in future.

My idea was to invest time to creation of automatic generator to save time in future and even possibly now because create a hundreds of reports which display simple db table is not so hard but time consuming.

Comment: I don't know if something like that with tools such as iReports. May be you can create your own utility for reading tables from the DB, get a simple jrxml template and then fill it based on a standard structure. For that you might try to use Dynamic Reports, which is an API based on JasperReports: http://www.dynamicreports.org/ . It gives you the opportunity to extract metadata from the object being loaded (i.e. the tables).